# SwiftUI make LazyGrid Item twice the size of other Items

Tags: swiftui

I want to display a grid where one item takes twice the amount of space of the others.

[Similar to this HTML Grid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3A4D0.png)

Basically I want the last item `Text("div4")` to take up the space of two items. I do not want to use `.fixed` since it should take exactly twice the space of the other grids no matter the screen size.

If there is a way to archive this without LazyGrid, that is also fine with me ;)

Here is my current code:

```
let cols = [GridItem(.flexible()), GridItem(.flexible()), GridItem(.flexible()), GridItem(.flexible())]

var body : some View {
    
    LazyVGrid(columns: cols){
        Text("div1")
        Text("div2")
        Text("div3")
        Text("div4")
    }
}
```

Comment: You can’t in iOS 15 and below, the new methods allow it in iOS 16+

Comment: @loremipsum and there is no workaround?

Comment: You can manually do it with VStacks and HStacks but no loop way of doing the task. This question has been asked many times there are many solutions on SO.

Comment: Could you please point me in the right direction?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Since Swift does not support this. A solution would be to use a library like: **ExyteGrid**!

```
var body : some View {
    
    Grid(tracks: [.fr(1),.fr(1),.fr(1),.fr(2)]){
        Text("div1")
        Text("div2")
        Text("div3")
        Text("div4")
    }
}
```

https://cocoapods.org/pods/ExyteGrid